# Best place to handle sockets in a React application using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, socket.io, react-context

I am currently working on a react-native real-time application (a chat app) and I was wondering which would be the better place to manage the socket connection and events handlers (using socket.io).
I am using Redux as global state management, and so I was first thinking of managing the socket in a middleware. But then I thought it could be a good choice to implement it using React context API. The provider would only provide the socket itself to children, and so would not directly trigger any rendering (incoming events would dispatch redux actions).
Today React context mainly suffers from poor rendering optimizations, but in this case this wouldn't be a problem.

How do you manage your sockets connections in your React apps that use Redux? Everything using Redux with middlewares? Or do you combine it with the context API? Do you seen any cons in doing this way?

Thanks!